# Residuals for Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, residuals

I have read that there are multiple ways to look at residuals for logistic regression. I am not necessarily that interested in analyzing the residuals for a logit model, but my main question is rather:

Where are residuals in the specification of the model?

For linear models, it's common to write
$$y=X\beta+\varepsilon \ \ \text{ or } \ \   y = \beta_0+\beta_1x_1 + \dots + \beta_kx_k+\varepsilon$$

However, for the logit model I keep finding
$$l=\log\frac{p}{1-p}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1 + \dots + \beta_kx_k  \ \ \text{ or } \ \    p = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_1x_1 + \dots + \beta_kx_k)}}$$

How come the disturbances are not *part* of the model in this case?

**Edit:**

I have thought of something but am not sure if this is the complete reasoning behind it. In my understanding, a linear model assumes that data have been generated according to $y=X\beta$ with random disturbances, as nothing is perfectly linear.

And for a logit model this disturbance is not needed, as the data are assumed to be generated(?) according to $p$: at every point $x_i$ there is a certain probability $p$ that the outcome will be $1$, and the points $y=0,1$ are generated according to this, rather than a set linear relation with disturbances that make it random.

Comment: For logistic regression, the role of $R^2$ is taken by "Pseudo $R^2$", for which different definitions are in use. All have in common that they are not based on residuals but on ratios between likelihood values. If you search for "pseudo r squared" and "logistic regression", you should find some possible definitions.

Comment: You should distinguish *error* i.e. $\epsilon_i = Y_i-\mu_i(X_i, \beta)$ (where $\mu_i$ is a conditional mean that depends on $X_i$ and parameter $\beta$ and is unique), from *residuals* i.e. $Y_i-\mu_i(X_i, \hat{\beta})$ (with estimated $\beta$, which will be different each data set). Both always exist, but $var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$ won't be parameterized when it's already determined by the mean e.g. in logistic regression's Bernoulli distrib. assumption. That linear regression requires Normality and therefore $\mu_i$ *and* $\sigma^2$ makes it necessary to write $\epsilon$ into the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have residuals, or not, in either case. But to start with, you don't need residuals at all to specify the model: In either case, you can write $$Y|X=x \ \ \sim \ \  p(y|x),$$ where $p(y|x)$ is some conditional distribution. In the case of logistic regression, $p(y|x)$ is a Bernoulli distribution. In the case of classical regression, $p(y|x)$ is a normal distribution, but this can be relaxed to allow other forms, like Poisson, negative binomial, multinomial, non- or semi-parametric variants, etc.

If you want residuals, you can also have them, in either case: For an observation where $X=x$, the residual is $\epsilon = Y - E(Y|X=x)$.  In the case of standard regression, under the usual linearity assumption, this gives you $$\epsilon = Y - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x).$$  In the case of logistic regression, under the usual linearity (of logit) assumption, this gives you $$\epsilon = Y - \frac{\exp{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}}{1+\exp{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}},$$ where $Y$ is either 0 or 1.

It is just not common to use this form in the case of logistic regression because the salient feature of the model is the form of the conditional Bernoulli distribution of $Y|X=x$.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it is formulated in such abstract terms that the original poster presumably won't understand it. I would suggest to add an explanation how $E(Y|X=x)$ is computed from the estimated coefficients $\beta_i$.

Comment: Thanks; edited.

Comment: The last equation is used as the summand for calculating the Brier score, which measures the accuracy of probabilistic predictions.